# image upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload image in codeigniter in localhost.But the image is not get uploaded.Is there any changes in the config file needed.The controller I have used is shown below...

```
<?php

class upload extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array(
            'url',
            'form',
            'html'
        ));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form');
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = '../uploads/';

        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '500';
        $config['max_width']     = '1024';
        $config['max_height']    = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            $this->load->view('upload_form');
        } else {
            //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success');
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: So what `$this->upload->display_errors()` return ?

Comment: is your file extension in "allowed_types" list...

Comment: what error are you getting???

Comment: what is the contents of upload_form view?

Comment: Have you checked in error log file?

Comment: Does your form have the multipart attribute? And does the file input have the name "userfile"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your folder permissions to make sure your `'../uploads/'` folder can be written to.